# vb.net DexExpress winform GridControl click column header select cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I use `GridControl` with `Gridview` to display the data. I realized I click the column header is sorting the data instead of select all cell under the column header. May I know how to handle this? I have a sample code (below) but it use `BandedGridview`.

```
Private Sub bandedGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles bandedGridView1.MouseDown
    If Control.ModifierKeys <> (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Control) Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim view As BandedGridView = CType(sender, BandedGridView)
    Dim hInfo As BandedGridHitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location)
    If hInfo.InColumn Then
        view.ClearSelection()
        SelectCells(hInfo.Column)
    ElseIf hInfo.InBandPanel AndAlso hInfo.Band IsNot Nothing Then
        view.ClearSelection()
        SelectCells(hInfo.Band)
    Else
        Return
    End If
    CType(e, DXMouseEventArgs).Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub SelectCells(ByVal column As BandedGridColumn)
    For i As Integer = 0 To column.View.RowCount - 1
        column.View.SelectCell(i, column)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub SelectCells(ByVal band As GridBand)
    For Each column As BandedGridColumn In band.Columns
        SelectCells(column)
    Next column
End Sub
```

I need `GridView` only, anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this code for `GridView` then you can just remove the word `Banded` from everywhere and remove anything that belongs to `GridBand`. For `SelectedCells` method you need to convert `column.View` to `GridView`. Also I suggest you to add `GridView.BeginSelection` and `GridView.EndSelection` methods into `SelectedCells` method.
Here is example:

```
Imports DevExpress.Utils
Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns
Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid
Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.ViewInfo

'...

Private Sub gridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles gridView1.MouseDown
    If Control.ModifierKeys <> (Keys.Shift Or Keys.Control) Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim view As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
    Dim hInfo As GridHitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location)
    If hInfo.InColumn Then
        view.ClearSelection()
        SelectCells(hInfo.Column)
    Else
        Return
    End If
    CType(e, DXMouseEventArgs).Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub SelectCells(ByVal column As GridColumn)
    Dim view As GridView = CType(column.View, GridView)

    view.BeginSelection()

    For i As Integer = 0 To view.RowCount - 1
        view.SelectCell(i, column)
    Next i

    view.EndSelection()
End Sub
```

Comment: Ya that was my idea too, but so many error when i remove the banded.

CType(e, DXMouseEventArgs).Handled = True
and
column.View.SelectCell(i, column)

Comment: @FirionRedfield Add `Imports DevExpress.Utils` for `DXMouseEventArgs` and cast `column.View` to `GridView`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I realize if i add these code to GridView, other function such as sorting by clicking column header is disabled.

Comment: @FirionRedfield In your code there are `Keys.Shift` and `Keys.Control` modifiers. So, If you use this modifiers, then other functions is disabled only when `Shift` and `Control` is pressed.

Comment: Okay, for my case instead of press shift and control to select all column by clicking column header, I also have one selection which is select all row when click the most top left like Excel. The problem i face is either one work....
I updaded the code on my post

Comment: @FirionRedfield This is another question. You need to ask a new question in StackOverflow instead of editing the existing question.

Comment: I had post a question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541088/vb-net-devexperess-winforms-gridview-mouse-down-event